# Changes to array objects not saving to main ObservableObject

Tags: swiftui

I'm starting with SwiftUI and I'm running into a roadblock with array items of an `ObservableObject` not saving to the main object.

Main object:

```
class Batch: Codable, Identifiable, ObservableObject {
    let id: String
    var items = [Item]()
}
```

Item object:

```
class Item: Codable, Identifiable, ObservableObject {
    let id: String
    var description: String
}
```

I have a `BatchView` which I pass a batch into:

```
struct BatchView: View {
    @ObservedObject var batch: Batch

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(batch.items) { item in
                ItemView(item: item)
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(batch.items.reduce("", { $0 + $1.description }))
    }
}
```

In the `ItemView` I change the description:

```
struct ItemView: View {
    @ObservedObject var item: Item
    @State private var descr = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("MANUFACTURED")
            TextField("", text: $descr) {
                self.updateDescr(descr: self.descr)
            }
        }
    }

    private func updateDescr(descr: String) {
        item.description = descr
    }
}
```

But when I update the description for a batch item, the title of `BatchView` doesn't change, so the changes to the `Item` isn't coming back to the root `Batch`.

How do I make the above work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57736611/2335677) helped me. I had to explicitly add `@Published` in front of the variable I was changing.