# SwiftUI access global state from ViewModel

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, swiftui, combine

I am experimenting with SwiftUI and having a hard time figuring out the proper architecture for my app.

What I am trying to achieve is simple. I want to have an initial screen that either show a sign up screen or the home screen for a given user depending on current authentication state. I cannot figure out how to make the initial screen pick up changes from the sign up screen once authentication has taken place. Here's some relevant code:

```swift
struct InitialView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: InitialViewModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if viewModel.auth.identity != nil {
                NewHomeView()
            } else {
                SignInView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the sign in view, I have a usual sign in form and when the user presses the sign in button, I want to send a login request to the backend and remember the resulting token.

```swift
class SignInViewModel: ObservableObject {
    private let auth: AuthStore
    private let signInApi: SignInApi
    private var cancellableSet: Set<AnyCancellable>

    // Input
    @Published var name: String = ""
    @Published var password: String = ""
    @Published var showSignUp: Bool = false

    // Output
    @Published var authSuccess: Bool = false

    init(auth: AuthStore, signInApi: SignInApi) {
        self.auth = auth
        self.signInApi = signInApi
        self.cancellableSet = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    }

    func signIn() {
        signInApi.signIn(email: name, password: password).sink(receiveCompletion: { _ in }) { response in
            self.auth.identity = Identity(
                person: Person(id: 1, name: "user", sex: nil, birthday: nil),
                token: response.token
            )
            self.authSuccess = true
        }.store(in: &cancellableSet)
    }
}
```

HOWEVER, this does not work. Even after clicking the sign in button, the initial view is not updated. Note that I am passing the same AuthStore to both view models.

```swift
  let auth = AuthStore()

        // Create the SwiftUI view that provides the window contents.
        let contentView = InitialView()
            .environmentObject(InitialViewModel(auth: auth))
            .environmentObject(SignInViewModel(auth: auth, signInApi: SignInApi()))
```

where AuthStore is defined as

```
class AuthStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published var identity: Identity? = nil
}
```

Ideally, I'd love to be able to 1) have each view be paired with its own VM 2) have each VM access global state via @EnvironmentObject. However, it seems that @EnvironmentObject is restricted to views only? If so, how do I access the global auth state from within each VM that requires it?

Comment: Have you tried a little project with this tutorial ? https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-environmentobject-to-share-data-between-views There is two views by the way... exactly what you want to learn

Comment: Hey, I looked at that link before asking. I didn't go with it because it basically forces me to stop using MVVM and do all state management inside the view. In the language of the link you posted, I'd love to have two View Models with access to the same UserSettings (ideally injected once from within the SceneDelegate). Is that possible?

Comment: see the discussion below the answer there, you have to check what @Published wrapper is for, and how it works https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60119057/swiftui-propagating-change-notifications-through-nested-reference-types/60126962#60126962

Comment: another question, which environment object will be accessible in your contentView ???

Comment: I answered something similar here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60134061/how-to-push-a-new-root-view-using-swiftui-without-navigationlink/60424968#60424968

Comment: From my understand this topic is very complicated. It has been solved with architectures like Redux, VIPER, and dependency injection. Having a global state mutated from different view models is dangerous. But if you are looking for something quick and dirty you can just have the authentication state be a singleton.

Answer (score 0):

As on provided code I would change it as following

```
struct InitialView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: InitialViewModel
    @EnvironmentObject var signIn: SignInViewModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if signIn.authSuccess {
                NewHomeView()
            } else {
                SignInView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

as well redirect publisher to main thread in

```
    signInApi.signIn(email: name, password: password)
        .receive(on: RunLoop.main) // << following update should be on main thread
        .sink(receiveCompletion: { _ in }) { response in
        self.auth.identity = Identity(
            person: Person(id: 1, name: "user", sex: nil, birthday: nil),
            token: response.token
        )
        self.authSuccess = true
    }.store(in: &cancellableSet)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for that. I'll try it. A small note of clarification: the view model for the initial view only has auth and no authSuccess.

Comment: the missing part in his example is some link between SignInViewModel and InitialViewModel.  At least i don't see that ...

Comment: Update: nope, for some reason when I update auth.identity even though it's @Published, etc. it still doesn't register. I have a feeling this might be because changes in nested observableobjects are not propagated up. I tried doing something like self.isAuthenticated = self.auth.$identity.map { $0 != nil } in the InitialViewModel but I can't get the types right. In Rx this would have been just an observable but Combine encodes the computation in the type system and it quickly becomes a mess.. :( \

Comment: @user3441734 I want the link to be the shared AuthStore that I pass to both ViewModels (InitialViewModel and SignInViewModel).

Comment: he wrote "Note that I am passing the same AuthStore to both view models" ... ???? It is hard to understand his business logic from his example

Comment: @user3441734 I'll update the question to demonstrate what I mean.

Comment: OK, I've probably got your point ... see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60119057/swiftui-propagating-change-notifications-through-nested-reference-types/60126962#60126962

Comment: setting value to auth.identity will NOT force to update UI, jst because the auth is reference type (and correctly defined as private let auth: .....)

Comment: did you ever try to have two @EnvironmentObject wrappers in one View?

Answer (score 0):

Venture a guess here since you didn't provide InitialViewModel details.

You didn't observe `auth` in `SignInViewModel`, and didn't publish it to tigger view update.

I'm guessing it's the same problem with InitialViewModel.

```
class SignInViewModel: ObservableObject {
    private let auth: AuthStore
    private let signInApi: SignInApi
```

To question 2): you can't. (as far as I know)

To question 1): you can. But at what cost? Are there better alternatives?

I can elaborate more if needed.