# Programmatically segue from SwiftUI to UITabBarController

Tags: uikit, uitabbarcontroller, segue, swiftui

I have an existing application that I want to replace the existing UIKit based on-boarding with one I wrote in SwiftUI.  I successfully used vc = UIHostingController(rootView: mySwiftUIView()) and self.window.rootViewController = vc in my AppDelegate to load it the first time the App's is run.  So I have the UIKit to SwiftUI portion working.

At the end of the SwiftUI on-boarding I have a button that I want to use to segue to the main application VC.  **One option is to use the following:**

```
sheet(isPresented: $initialVCPresented) {
                    VCSwiftUIView(storyboard: "Main", VC: "RootVC")
                }
```

with, ...

```
//
//  VCSwiftUIView.swift
//
//  Created by Schumacher, Dan on 2/12/20.
//  Copyright © 2020 Schumacher, Dan. All rights reserved.
//

import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct VCSwiftUIView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    let storyboard: String
    let VC: String

  func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<VCSwiftUIView>) -> AnimatedTabBarController {

    //Load the storyboard
    let loadedStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboard, bundle: nil)

    //Load the ViewController
     return loadedStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: VC) as! AnimatedTabBarController
  }

  func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: AnimatedTabBarController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<VCSwiftUIView>) {
  }
}
```

But this shows the UIKit VC modally, which I do not want.

I don't believe I can uses NavigationLink(destination: MainVC)) as MainVC is not a Navigation Controller.

Can anyone offer me any suggestions on how to **segue from my SwiftUI View to a UITabBarContoller?**

UPDATE:

I tried the following code within the action for my SwiftUI Button. I can see that the UIKit TabBarVC is called (the RootVC on the storyboard points to a UITabBarViewController) via print statements in the console, and the screen flashes, but the SwiftUI View remains on the screen.  Any ideas why the UIKit VC isn't being displayed?

```
let window:UIWindow = UIWindow()
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let rootVC: UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RootVC")
window.rootViewController = rootVC
window.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: Actually I would just replace root view controller in window. I suppose the approach in [How to push a new root view using SwiftUI without NavigationLink?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60134243/12299030) will be helpful.

Comment: I tried this and couldn't get the UIKit VC to display, even though I can see that it ws called (via print statements to the console).  I updated my question with more details.

Comment: You create new window on stack so it is just released at once. Instead you need to find current window (via SceneDelegate as shown in proposed code) and replace its root controller (which is hosting SwiftUI controller) with new one loaded from storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

**Thanks** for everyone help and direction.  The solution was fairly simple once I got your suggestions.  I just created a VStack inside a ZStack, and turned the opacity to 0.0 until the button was tapped, whereas I set the opacity to 1.0, and to 0.0 for the prior VStack.  The button action is to simply update the initialVC Presented boolean state variable.

```
            VStack {
                VCSwiftUIView(storyboard: "Main", VC: "RootVC")
            }
            .opacity(initialVCPresented ? 1.0 : 0.0)
            .animation(Animation.easeOut(duration: 2.0))
```

And the code for VCSwiftUIView is unchanged from that shown in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

A sheet of course shows a modal. You are allowed to use a NavigationLink 
like below ... The navigation destination can be **Any Swift UI View**. It need not be a navigation controller

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: VCSwiftUIView()) {
                    Text("Show VC Swift UI View")
                }.navigationBarTitle("Animated Tab Bar")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe this would be the way to 'segue' to a SwiftUI Tab View.  I have a **UIKit UITabBarViewController** I am trying to transition to.  Did you misunderstand my question (perhaps I wasn't clear enough on this point), or am I missing something here?

Comment: `Can anyone offer me any suggestions on how to segue from my SwiftUI View to a UITabBarContoller?` was your question !

Comment: Anyways if you want to transition the TabBar then you could try to do something like offset the view to phone screen height by putting in a ZStack and then changing the offset to 0 with animation on button tapped or something like that...