# SwiftUI how to call or notify scenedelegate from a view

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios-bluetooth, uiscenedelegate

I have some code (bluetooth manager) that I want to implement as a singleton for the application.

I read many tutorials online about passing environment variable & using observed object to share states, which is useful to pass data from scene delegate to views, like a list of found BT devices. However, how can views talk back to scene delegate?

For example, when the user click I a device, I would like to connect to it which requires the button click calling some method back into scene delegate where the singleton bluetooth manager resides?

Comment: You can see an example [in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60134243/12299030). The goal there is different, but the approach is the same.

Comment: @Asperi Ouch, right that notification thing. I'm still looking at good way to do it in swiftUI but that should work. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1):

### Potential solution:

Create a class conforming to `ObservableObject` with state variables and methods. Initiate it in scene delegate as a singleton object and then pass it to views as environment object.

Within each view, we will have access to methods & state within that shared singleton.